# Kendo ASP.NET MVC Wrapper Limitations

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can anyone let me know is there any limitations with Kendo MVC4 wrapper ? Can I use all the controls which Kendo Javascript api provides with same functionality with Kendo MVC?

Also Let me know can I use offline data with Asp.net MVC wrapper(Kendo MVC) such as web sql.

Thanks Chinthaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC wrappers are supposed to allow you to use the same controls and configuration options, although I suppose it's not impossible that you'll encounter a few limitations in practice, esp. with new features.

There is no special support in Kendo UI for client-side storage, so you'll have to manage that yourself independently (with JavaScript).

Comment: Hey Lars Thanks for your response ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I work for telerik - so my answer may be biased.

Kendo UI wrappers for ASP.NET MVC is just a helper/wrapper pretty similar to vanilla MVC controls. For e.g. You have Html.Label which outputs  markup for you. Kendo UI is a HTML5 based client side UI framework. So you need JS code on the client side to instantiate the kendo UI control. So inorder to create a grid you will have to say $("#element").kendoGrid(). If you are a dev who likes to be in the razor and C# world and,doesn't want to write JS, you can go the route of wrappers. So to create a grid you will just say @(Html.Kendo().Grid().Name("kGrid"). The wrapper will generate the required JS for you when the response is generated.

Wrappers are available for all the controls in Kendo UI Suite.

The client API can be used to perform any client side runtime changes you may want to perform.

Comment: Thanks Lohith So I would go for Client Side scripting :-)

Comment: @Lohith you said  The wrapper will generate the required JS for you when the response is generated. 

Where does the this JavaScript gets generated - in the parent HTML page ? or on a separate JS file ?

If I need to minify/obfuscate all JS would the usage of MVC wrappers restrict this ?

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement Lars answer above, there is a good article on the web demo application (Kendo Music Store) that uses local storage to make a shopping cart written by the folks at Telerik/KendoUI. It is worth it to check it out. See [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-cart).

Comment: Thanks Stargazer It's really helpful ;-) Thanks again